# Passing correct variable to partial in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, partials

I am trying to show all the companies in a portfolio in Rail 7 and can't figure out the right variable(s) to pass from the Portfolios page to the Companies partial. The companies model has_many: portfolios and Portfolios has_many: companies. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In Portfolios\index.html.erb, I have tried

```
<%= render "portfolios/companies", company: portfolio.company_id%> 
<%= render "portfolios/companies", @company %> 
<%= render "portfolios/companies", portfolio: @portfolio %>
```

In the partial porfolios/_companies.html.erd, I have tried

```
<%= render portfolio.companies %>
<%= render 'companies/company', @company %>
```

Each had different errors, such as NilClass and "Undefined local variable or method `company'"

Comment: It is not good idea to use instance variables in partials. You can pass local variable to partial, but can't pass instance variable using usual flow. Instance variables are for views

Comment: What companies do you want to show on portfolios index page? Do you assign some instance variable for that in your controller?

Comment: @mechnicov Thank you. I appreciate your feedback and will look into the difference a bit more. Still new to Rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to display every company for every portfolio on one page... that sounds a little messy but it can be done.

This assumes your `index` action sets `@portfolios`. In `portfolios\index.html.erb`:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <td>Portfolio</td>
    <td>Company list</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @portfolios.each do |portfolio| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= portfolio.name %></td>
        <td>
          <%= render "portfolios/companies", companies: portfolio.companies %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then in `porfolios/_companies.html.erb`, the `companies` variable would contain a collection of companies:

```
<ul>
  <% companies.each do |company| %>
    <li><%= company.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The result should look something like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I will mark it as the answer as it got me most of the way there. I would add that I needed to create a companies_portfolios table as it would not try to access my portfolios_companies table - do you by any chance know why? It is because of the order of the variables?

Comment: In other cases, the view tried to access portfolio_id in the Companies table, when I wanted it to find the company_id in the Portfolios table. Again, I think the crux of my question has to do with the ordering (I think)

Comment: @ASing: The above assumes you've set it all up The Rails Way™ but Ruby is very flexible and Rails can seem a bit like magic at first so there's lots of ways to make assumptions or mistakes. If you add your models to the question we can help troubleshoot a bit more but it sounds like you might actually want https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association in your models

Comment: Yes, thank you. That's exactly the guide I've been following. Will continue to go through it. Thanks.